# 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to execute my Selenium Webdriver in python, but unable to go any further, I am running a basic script, like

```
   from selenium import webdriver


    driver = webdriver.Chrome
```

On which I am seeing this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/new/PycharmProjects/Selenium/Staring/RunTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/new/PycharmProjects/Selenium/Starting/chromedriver.exe')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Can someone please help or assist me.

Comment: find your path to chromedriver.exe, click start, type environment, select edit environment variables & add the path (excluding the exe) to the user or system PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide path for you `chromedriver`

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('your/chromedriver/path')
```

You able to check where is your `chromedriver` located via command.

`which chromedriver`

Comment: @TaimoorPasha Which OS you are using?

Comment: @TaimoorPasha if Windows, you need to set path something like  `driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/michael/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add chromedriver binary to your home folder
Can be downloaded here
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18013321)

Comment: This link to binaries download page doesnt answer to any question. It is simply the link to chromedriver download page.